# CartThrob Product Options Inventory

Tags: cartthrob

I am wondering. Is there way to include inventory levels with each product option in CartThrob Pro?

e.g. 10 Smalls, 5 Mediums, 2 Larges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as long as you only need to track inventory on one set of product options.

Map 'Product Inventory Field Name' to your product options field in the Cartthrob/Products settings page.

The default Cartthrob fieldtype needs no additional configuration.
If you are using a Matrix field, make sure you have an `{inventory}` column.

If you need to track inventory over multiple product option groups, take a look at their [Price Modifiers Configurator Fieldtype](http://cartthrob.com/docs/fieldtypes/price_modifiers_configurator/index.html).